# How to change GET to POST

Tags: post, get, xss, csrf, owasp

I have one web application running on Struts. User is hitting below url directly from browser - 
http://:/Test/servlet.do?name=XX&address=YYY

By default this request is submitted as GET by the user. Now my question is
1) how do I change user request to POST?

Comment: How does the user get/create that GET URL?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of browser add-ons that will let you send your request as POST (such as [DHC by Restlet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-resthttp-api-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm) and Advanced REST client for Chrome)

Comment: Thanks Mike, but my requirement is not to use any add-ons, user should not be allowed to send GET request.

Comment: @user3169438 can you provide more information then? like some code that you have written?

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery `post` or `ajax` methods, using an empty form with hidden keys.

Answer (score 0):

Remember GET is inside the  ans is set into links.  POST are usually done by , or GET is possible too.  So hitting a URL or link as you said is not possible to do over html,   use PHP or Jquery so have it GET instead .